# Issues in serverside of GCM

Tags: java, rest, google-cloud-messaging

im trying to test push notification using GCM in android device. Just i run the server side test with piece of available in stackoverflow. but i got **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/univ/entity/GCMTestingClient**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

public class GCMTestingClient {
    public String  GCMTest() throws IOException {
        Sender sender = new Sender("AszEaAipXqOJl--lMKSk6qHiOO7zmavU3cRQPk");
        Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .collapseKey("1")
                .timeToLive(3)
                .delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData("hello",
                        "this text will be seen in notification bar!!").build();

        Result result = sender.send(message, "93821834343", 1);
        System.out.println("result" + result);
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            GCMTestingClient gcm=new GCMTestingClient();
            gcm.GCMTest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

help me to solve this issue.

Error message :

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/univ/entity/GCMTestingClient
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.univ.entity.GCMTestingClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running app using

```
java com.univ.entity.GCMTestingClient
```

?

If yes, then you are missing package name on top of your code:

```
package  com.univ.entity
```

Basically, your error is saying that java cant find the class you are trying to run. You should be in the top level directory and see "com/univ/entity/" directory with GCMTestingClient class.

Comment: i have included **package com.univ.entity**; in top of the class still i got this error

Comment: Have you recompiled the class? How you are running the code, from command line or ide?

Comment: its working man... Just i clean and run the project it working :) thanks man.